# What is the average Levenshtein distance between two random binary strings of length $L$?

Tags: probability, coding-theory, binary

For example, for length $L=7$, two random binary strings might be:

```
0100101
1010011
```

The Levenshtein distance here would be 5, as it would require 5 bit-flips to change one to the other.

I attempted a derivation on paper that led me to $$\frac{1}{2^L}\sum_{k=0}^{L}\left(k\cdot{L\choose{k}}\right)$$ which Mathematica gracefully simplified to $$\frac{L}{2}$$

This *seems* correct, but (my) intuition can often be misleading. If true, though, it'd be inconsistent with something else I'm working with (another person's work), and I'd like to have more confidence before raising question. Surprisingly, I don't see anything on Google, either.

**Could anyone point to a source regarding, or confirm by their own derivation, what the average Levenshtein distance between two random binary strings of length $L$, is?**

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**

@vadim123 has shown me that my premises were wrong. Pulled from his comment:

> What you are calling Levenshtein distance is commonly called Hamming distance. For example, 01010101 and 10101010 have Hamming distance 8, but Levenshtein distance 2 (add a 1 at the beginning, delete a 1 at the end).

The actual Levenshtein distance of my example is 2!

```
 0100101
a
10100101
      d
101001 1
```

So, now, I'm at a complete loss. **What *is* the real formula, then? Is there one?**

Comment: >The Levenshtein distance here would be 5, as it would require 5 bit-flips to change one to the other.

I don't understand this comment. Do you define Levenstein distance as the required number of bit-flips to change one into the other?

Comment: @xyzzyz - Yes, that's how I _was_ defining it, but if that's wrong, then that may very well be the source of the inconsistency! Given two strings of equal length, how could Levenshtein distance refer to anything else, _i.e._ insertions and deletions?

Comment: What you are calling Levenshtein distance is commonly called Hamming distance.  For example, $01010101$ and $10101010$ have Hamming distance 8, but Levenshtein distance 2 (add a 1 at the beginning, delete a 1 at the end).

Comment: @vadim123 - You have definitely found the cause of my confusion, thank you. I've edited my answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $X_i$ to be the 0/1 random variable denoting whether two binary strings differ in position $i$.  These $L$ random variables are independent, and each 0/1 with equal probability.  By linearity of expectation, $E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_L)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots+E(X_L)=1/2+1/2+\cdots+1/2=L/2$.

Comment: This is to answer the Hamming distance question, i.e. if only bit swaps are allowed.